# rsync permission fail cannot open directory

Tags: centos, rsync, centos6

i encounter a problem when troubleshooting rsync server and client.

```
rsync: opendir "/." (in pub) failed: Permission denied (13)
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2014/01/27 12:02:24 .
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1536) [generator=3.0.9]
```

My /etc/rsyncd.conf is as below.

```
max connections = 2
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
timeout = 300

[pub]
    comment = random thing available for download
    path = /home/backup/test
    read only = yes
    list = yes
    uid = nobody
    gid = nobody
    auth users = admin
    secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

I have chmod 600 for both /etc/rsyncd.conf and /etc/rsyncd.secrets seeking for advice.

Comment: @Janne is correct this is a permission issue, the user nobody doesn't have read permission to the test directory.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the permissions for `/home/backup` or `/home` are too restrictive for `nobody` uid/gid. Please check those, too. It's not enough to have relaxed access to `/home/backup/test` if some earlier path prevents the access.